# QTableView does not show values in column after setItemDelegateForColumn

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I haveve implemented a table model (inherited `QAbstractTableModel`) and added it on a `QTableView`.

I wanted to add delegate to use custom edit widgets for my data items (for example, use a `QSlider` for some double values). Alas, after I've added a delegate, the table view does not shows values in this column anymore.

Can anyone tell me, how to fix it?

Here's the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys

from enum import IntEnum, unique
from collections import OrderedDict

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


@unique
class BGModelCols(IntEnum):
    alpha = 0
    alpha_for_nans = 1
    color_map = 2
    is_boolean = 3
    x_size_px = 4
    y_size_px = 5
    is_visible = 6


class ScanRadarSimulator(QtCore.QObject):
    backgrounds_supported = ["height", "elevation", "visibility", "closing_angles", "land_rcs"]

    @property
    def background_names(self):
        return [self.tr("Land height"), self.tr("Elevation"), self.tr("Visibility"), self.tr("Closing angles"),\
               self.tr("Land RCS")]

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


class BackgroundTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, radar_simulator, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._radar_simulator = radar_simulator
        self._background_names = self._radar_simulator.background_names
        assert isinstance(self._radar_simulator, ScanRadarSimulator)

        self.column_names = {BGModelCols.alpha: self.tr("α-channel"),
                             BGModelCols.alpha_for_nans: self.tr("α-channel for NANs"),
                             BGModelCols.color_map: self.tr("Color map"),
                             BGModelCols.is_boolean: self.tr("Is boolean mask"),
                             BGModelCols.x_size_px: self.tr("X pixels"),
                             BGModelCols.y_size_px: self.tr("Y pixels"),
                             BGModelCols.is_visible: self.tr("Is visible")}

        self._background_items = OrderedDict()
        for bg_id in radar_simulator.backgrounds_supported:
            bg_dict = {BGModelCols.alpha: 0.7,
                       BGModelCols.alpha_for_nans: 0.0,
                       BGModelCols.color_map: "jet",
                       BGModelCols.is_boolean: False,
                       BGModelCols.x_size_px: 4000,
                       BGModelCols.y_size_px: 4000,
                       BGModelCols.is_visible: False}
            self._background_items[bg_id] = bg_dict

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._radar_simulator.backgrounds_supported)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(BGModelCols)

    def flags(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def data(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex(), role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        row, col = index.row(), index.column()
        print("DATA", row, col)
        col_item = BGModelCols(col)

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._background_items[radar_simulator.backgrounds_supported[row]][col_item])
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return self._background_items[radar_simulator.backgrounds_supported[row]][col_item]
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            row, col = index.row(), index.column()
            col_item = BGModelCols(col)
            self._background_items[radar_simulator.backgrounds_supported[row]][col_item] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self.column_names[BGModelCols(section)]
            elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                return self._background_names[section]
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()


class AlphaChannelDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        print("CREATING EDITOR")
        slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(parent)
        slider.setMinimum(0)
        slider.setMaximum(100)
        slider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        return slider

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        # row, col = index.row(), index.column()
        # col_item = BGModelCols(col)
        # model._background_items[model._radar_simulator.backgrounds_supported[row]][col_item] = editor.value() / 100.
        print("setModelData")
        model.setData(index, editor.value() / 100., QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        print("setEditorData")
        row, col = index.row(), index.column()
        col_item = BGModelCols(col)
        val = int(index.model()._background_items[index.model()._radar_simulator.backgrounds_supported[row]][col_item] * 100)
        editor.setValue(val)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyle("fusion")

    radar_simulator = ScanRadarSimulator()

    table_view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    alpha_delegate = AlphaChannelDelegate(table_view)

    table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(int(BGModelCols.alpha), alpha_delegate)
    table_view.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)
    table_view.setModel(BackgroundTableModel(radar_simulator))
    table_view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your `AlphaChannelDelegate.paint` method doesn't draw any data. Try to comment it out to get the default drawing behaviour.

Comment: remove paint method or use this code: `def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        opt.text = index.data()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, opt, painter)`

Comment: Thanks, I've removed out the `paint` method. Just now the text is drawn even in the cell where is drawn the slider. Is it okay?
https://imgur.com/a/ZGVeO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it will work if comment out the `paint` method.
^_^